# What is the criteria to determine if a point lies within a polyline?

Tags: java, javafx-8, polyline

I am looking at the [Polyline](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Polyline.html) class from JavaFX. It inherits quite a few APIs from the [Node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) class. There is an API called [contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#contains-double-double-) that takes in  x and y coordinates and determines if the given point lies within the polyline. Now since the polyline could be an open polygon, meaning the start and end point might be different, how does the API determine if the point is actually inside the polyline?

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the source code of javafx, it dispatches the call to the current toolkit's `strokeContains` method. Looking at the QuantumToolkit example, it does a simple "Is the point in the bounding rectangle of the polyline" calculation and returns that as the answer. However, I'd recommend testing if that is the case for the specific toolkit you are using.